# iOS get campaign URL responsible for download

Tags: ios, facebook-marketing-api, campaign-monitor

When i generate a 'campaign url', here:

```
https://analytics.itunes.apple.com/#/campaigngenerator?app=$myappid
```

If my campaign is called 'facebook', then the url is:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id$myappid?pt=...&ct=facebook&mt=8
```

If my campaign is called 'pinterest', then the url is:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id$myappid?pt=...&ct=pinterest&mt=8
```

Assuming i'm running ads on facebook and pinterest.

Then, in the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

Is there a function I can call like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]     get_campaign_url_for_download:^(NSString*) URL 
{
  NSLog(@"link I clicked to download this app was %@",URL);
}];
```

To know whether that user downloaded my app through my Pinterest campaign URL or my Facebook campaign URL?

Comment: No, such a thing doesn't exist. There are ways to determine what you want using external services, but it isn't direct.

Comment: External services? If I can't do it using pure Apple resources how would someone else (IDFA being unable to be harvested now)

Comment: It's handled using a variety of tools server side. The details are trade secrets, but it works off a combination of IP, location, and cookies. The AdjustSDK is one such tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official reply from Apple is

```
Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). Our engineers have reviewed your request and have concluded that there is no supported way to achieve the desired functionality given the currently shipping system configurations.
```

If Apple cannot support this functionality then I am 100% certain there is no external service that can provide this functionality either